# MissingMethodException in Grails Bootstrap on Tomcat

Tags: grails, spring-security, bootstrapping, missingmethodexception

after updating my grails app's security plugins, i get the following error when deploying to tomcat:

2012-01-17 09:13:04,970 [pool-2-thread-1] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.BootstrapException: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.example.SecRole.findByAuthority() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [ROLE_USER]

the app works fine when being tested via run-app.

the SecRole class has been automatically generated by the spring security plugin.

i had previously deployed the app on the same server without a problem when using an older version of the spring security plugin.

have been knocking my head against this for hours. ideas much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at the WEB-INF/grails.xml file in the WAR. Does it contain an entry for SecRole?

Comment: Yes, there are entries for the security-plugin generated files in the grails.xml file in the war:     <resource>org.example.SecRole</resource>
<resource>org.example.SecUser</resource>
<resource>org.example.SecUserSecRole</resource>

Comment: any chance upgrading to grails2.0 might help?

Comment: I've just tested with Grails 2.0 and it works fine. So it's something specific to Grails 1.3.7 (or perhaps all 1.3.x versions).

Comment: thanks, upgrading to 2.0 did address that issue, though it introduced a host of others :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Peter's comment above, upgrading to Grails 2.0 solved the problem I described above. However, I had subsequently run into a host of upgrade issues with the app.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in v1.2.7 of the plugin. I released v1.2.7.1 to fix it; you can also downgrade to v1.2.6.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using your own Spring Security's User and Role class?

Did you tried to create a fresh grails project and install it with vacation request sample app to test it out?

Lastly, may I know which Grails version and OS you use?

Cheers,

Chee Kin

Comment: Yes, I am using my own User and Role classes, as per the hubbub sample app. Actually hubbub serves as the basis of my app. I am on Mac OS X Snow Leopard, using Grails 1.3.7 with STS. And I've just upgraded to spring-security-core 1.2.7 and spring-security-ui 0.1.2

Answer (score 0):

My prod Env: Tomcat 7, Fedora, Grails 1.3.7, activiti-spring-security 0.4.6, spring-security-core 1.2.7 activiti 5.8.2

Dev Env: Mac OS 10.6, Grails 1.3.7, activiti-spring-security 0.4.6, spring-security-core 1.2.7, activiti 5.8.2

I have installed vacation request app on fresh grails project and that works fine when I run using grails run-app (both in dev and prod mode).

Comment: It appears to be a bug in spring-security-core plugin. I created a JIRA for it http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-156

Comment: that would be both a relief and a disappointment: it's good to know it's not my fault, but now we have to wait for the plugin team to fix it

Comment: isn't this a pretty critical issue? might the priority of the ticket not be upped? also, any ideas how we might work around this in the meantime?

Comment: ilyashev: Did you try with older version of the plugin? I am thinking of doing the same as this is a very critical and urgent issue for me.

Comment: Thanks to confirmation as this issue is not caused by activiti plugin.

Comment: upgrading to grails 2.0 addressed the issue described here